How to do repeated measures mixed effects analysis with covariate in R
I have a dataset that consists of the oxygen consumption (MO2) values for 3 different species of fish. My experiment was a repeated measures design where I measured MO2 of the same 14 fish per species at 4 different temperature points (15C, 20C, 25C and 30C). I also recorded the weight of all fish used in the study.
I am trying to run a mixed effects model in R with individual as a random variable (to accommodate the repeated measures design) and with weight included as a covariate (I have already ran an ANCOVA and confirmed weight as a significant covariate with MO2, so I want to make sure I account for that in the mixed effects analysis).
How would I do this R? Would I be able to do a Tukey post hoc test afterwards as well - I want to know how each of the species' MO2 values differ from each other within each temperature, in addition to how the MO2 values within each species differs from itself at different temperatures.
I set up my code like this:
# You can fit a mixed effects model with individual
#  as a random variable and weight as a covariate

# Fit the mixed effects model
model <- lmer(MO2 ~ Temperature + Weight + 
                (1|Species/Subject_ID), data = MO2mixed)

# View the summary of the model
summary(model)

but then when I try to do a post hoc test I can't because species is a random effect. R says it doesn't appear in the reference grid for the estimated marginal means (EMMs).
Does this set up make sense? How can I accommodate everything delineated above and get the comparisons I want in my post hoc test?

One of the fundamental limitations of treating a variable as a random effect is that you can no longer use standard frequentist hypothesis testing to ask questions about differences between the levels of that variable.
You can treat Species as a fixed effect and still nest Subject_ID within it, as follows:
MO2 ~ Temperature + Weight + Species +  (1|Species:Subject_ID)

If your Subject_ID labels are unique (e.g. if you label individuals of species A A1, A2, A3, ... and species B B1, B2, B3, rather than labeling individuals from both species 1, 2, 3 ...), then (1|Subject_ID) will work just as well as (1|Species:Subject_ID) — you can use whichever is clearer to you.
